# global path effect on local planning

Tags: ros, pathplanning, dwa, navfn

[image: Rosanswers logo]

hi everyone

I am interseted in pathplanning and i try to build my robot. As i understood, we can use navfn package for global pathplanning which means a path from the current robot state to the goal state. Another package that we should use is base_local_planner or something like it that works in velocity space and publishes messages for base controller. Something that i can not understand is relationship between these two planners. How a planner like DWA or Trajectory Rollout or other local planners considers this path?  I mean does this path effect the calculation for our local commands? Is there any reference which discusses this subject in a mathematical manner??

thanks:))

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/190865/global-path-effect-on-local-planning/) by [mohammad](https://answers.ros.org/users/19955/mohammad/) on ROS Answers with karma: 75 on 2014-08-21

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Global planning generates a set of waypoints between one location and another, while local planning takes those waypoints and calculates the trajectories, and outputs velocities (to execute the trajectories).

http://wiki.ros.org/dwa_local_planner provides numerous references on how the algorithm works in detail.

---

Originally posted by [paulbovbel](https://answers.ros.org/users/3632/paulbovbel/) with karma: 4518 on 2014-08-21

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [mohammad](https://answers.ros.org/users/19955/mohammad/) on 2014-08-21**:
I think global navigation means having a map which is travelled by localization and move_base packages. In this kind of navigation we have two planners too. A planner which construct a path and a planner for velocity command based on DWA. I think these two planners work at same time and they depends each other. In the local planner we dont have any map and localization but also these two planners work again. But i dont how they effect each other. Do you?? In this reference there is no expalanation about this.

**Comment by [paulbovbel](https://answers.ros.org/users/3632/paulbovbel/) on 2014-08-21**:
Sorry that was confusing, edited my answer above. Global/local navigation->planners